# What is the purpose of the channel in my seat?

Tags: saddle, health

What is the purpose of the channel in my seat? Is it just for comfort or does it have some medical benefits?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose of the channel in a bike saddle is to reduce pressure to the perineum, which can cause numbness and other long-term problems. This is a matter of both comfort and health, although not everyone is affected. Individual body type, saddle design, bike fit, and riding style work together to make saddle fit a very personal issue.

On a related note, some of the worries about erectile disfunction seem to be overstated, though this is still an open area of research. See: 
[Saddle Seats and Erectile Dysfunction - The myth Exploded](http://bicyclehabitat.com/articles/saddle-seats-and-erectile-dysfunction-the-myth-exploded-pg97.htm).

Comment: +1 Totally agree. As I noted in my answer on David's other question, you just need to find one that works for you. (http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/10689/2077)

Comment: The ED question is also addressed on [skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/does-riding-a-bicycle-reduce-sperm-count-male-fertility).

Comment: Also on bicycles.stackexchange.com: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5102/can-cycling-adversely-affect-male-fertility